# How to find the circular JSON reference in a cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm at a loss here, I'm having a lot of trouble finding the circular reference in this cloud function.  What am I missing?  Any help would be well received.

Thanks

Function:

```
exports.requestStudio = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

         
  const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  const authToken = 'XXXXXXXXToken';
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 
  const nameParam = req.query.name;
  const bodyParam = req.query.body;
  const leadParam = req.query.leadId;
  const phoneParam = req.query.phone
  console.log(req.query)
// const strippedNumber = phone.replace(/\D+/g, '');
const dest = '+1' + phoneParam
  try {
    return client.studio.flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXX')
    .executions
    .create({
        to: dest, 
        from: +1XXXXXXXXXX,
        body: bodyParam,
        leadId: leadParam,
        name: nameParam,
        phone: phoneParam
      },
      res.send(res),
      res.status(200).json({message:res}
        ))
   
  } catch(error) {
 console.log(error)

  }
 });
```

Comment: What are you trying to serialize with that `json()` call? `res`, which is likely a [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), is an internal Node structure, I don't expect that to be what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to send the response back.  I removed that portion and did not get that same error, so that's good.  On to the next issue with my code!  Thanks!